# Connection refused when using imap.rb to connect to imap.google.com

Tags: ruby, imap, gmail-imap

I'm trying to connect to a Gmail account (via [ruby-gmail gem](https://github.com/gmailgem/gmail), [gmail gem](https://github.com/dcparker/ruby-gmail), [gmail_xoauth gem](https://github.com/nfo/gmail_xoauth) over OAuth 2.0, but each method uses imap.rb) and getting:

> C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/imap.rb:1045:in `initialize': No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it. - connect(2) for "imap.gmail.com" port 993 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)

On the Gmail account I have:

1. Ensured it can be accessed through web login
2. Ensured it's activated
3. Enabled IMAP
4. Allowed access for insecure apps

In the connection I have:

1. Ensured it is made over SSL
2. Ensured it uses correct login details and tokens where applicable
3. Tried ports 993 and 465

What else could I try? How could I rule out the firewall being the issue, without having control over it?

Comment: Can you use an email client (Thunderbird, whatever) to connect to it using the same ports, login, password, etc?

Comment: Interesting, that connection fails as well with Gmail details in Outlook and with the same details in Entourage on a separate machine on the same network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> .. (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
>
> ...  How could I rule out the firewall being the issue, without having control over it?

It is probably a firewall. The error message says that the connection to the service got actively refused. Since it is working for me I doubt that it is google itself which is refusing the service so it must be a firewall in between.

Comment: Have verified this by trying the same script and set-up over a less secure connection.